# raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file") zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, numpy

Am trying to append Data to an Excel Sheet

If I create an excel sheet in normal way by opening excel sheet and inserting the data by typing maully to it and then saving it and use loadworkbook it works but when I create an excel sheet using "writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')" I get error.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
# new dataframe with same columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['E','F','G','H'],
                   'Age': [100,70,40,60]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('demo.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
# try to open an existing workbook
writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
# copy existing sheets
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
# read existing file
reader = pd.read_excel(r'demo.xlsx')
# write out the new sheet
df.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=len(reader)+1)

writer.close()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "excel1.py", line 8, in <module>
    writer.book = load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 316, in load_workbook
    data_only, keep_links)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1222, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py", line 1289, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Answer (score 0):

https://qastack.ru/programming/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas

```
FILE_NAME = 'pattern.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=FILE_NAME)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(FILE_NAME, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = wb
```